# Visual Studio disable playlist load on startup

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio loads a playlist when opening solution, and I can't find a way to disable this. The only related post I've seen at all is this one [What does "Load Playlist started" mean in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098570/what-does-load-playlist-started-mean-in-visual-studio) It suggests that closing the test explorer window will stop it, but that doesn't help for me. I don't have any unit tests(shame on me, I know) nor have I created a playlist. I can't seem to find any info on this anywhere else either. Anyone know how to disable this? I'm using VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to uncheck **Test -> Test Settings -> Keep Test Execution Engine Running** setting.

Restart Visual Studio for the changes to take effect.